# python packages/tools to daemonize application

Tags: python, daemon

I want to daemonize a python application. I've heard of forever and upstart for Node.js, are there similar tools I can use for python?

Answer (score 2):

There are many great libraries for this, such as:

[daemonize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemonize)

**Example:**

```
from time import sleep
from daemonize import Daemonize

pid = "/tmp/test.pid"


def main():
    while True:
        sleep(5)

daemon = Daemonize(app="test_app", pid=pid, action=main)
daemon.start()
```

**Update:**

If you just want something like a supervisor, process control, init, etc
I highly recommend you check out: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/supervisor

Comment: Does this take care of failovers as well? For example, if the app were to crash, would it restart?

Comment: No you'll want to use something like supervisor in that case. Sorry your question wasn't clear whether you wanted something like supervisor or a "daemonizing" library for your application code :)